# Failed upgrade to 18.04.1 Videos no longer play

Tags: upgrade, sound, firefox, google-chrome, video

i upgraded from 16.04.1 LTS to 18.04.1 LTS.  Both local and online videos will no longer play.  Specifically, when accessing youtube online, in chrome, the progress circle continues to spin.  in firefox progress circle also spins. Also notice that there is no sound.  What is best solution for resolution of this issue?